# Set default style by resources

Tags: android, android-styles

I have styles and styles-21 folder under resources. I want default style as `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)` app has to use `styles-21` style and if <21 then the styles folder style to be applied. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default styles folder is available.

To create styles v21, right click on res folder and choose New -> Android resource file, set the same name for the new file "styles", in Available qualifiers: choose the last item "Version" and finally set "Platform API level" 21.
It would automatically switch styles based on device API level.